# Understanding Luby's algorithm for the Maximal Independent Set problem

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I am trying to understand the Random Priority version of the parallel Luby's algorithm to find a maximal independent set (MIS).
In the analysis steps [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_independent_set#Random-priority_parallel_algorithm), the first bullet claims that a node *v* removes it's neighbor *w* if *r(v) < r(w)* and *r(v) < r(x)*, where *x* is a neighbor of *w* and *r(x)* is the random number of node *x*.

I do not understand why *r(v) < r(x)* needs to be true for *v* to remove it's neighbor *w*.
Isn't the fact that *r(v)* is less than that of all it's neighbors enough for it to be included in the MIS?